# Get data from database using a findOne() in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I have this schema:

```
const statsData = new mongoose.Schema({
  userID: {type: String},
  warned: {type: Number, default:0},
  warns: {type: Number, default:0},
  muted: {type: Number, default:0},
  mutes: {type: Number, default:0},
  banned: {type: Number, default:0},
  bans: {type: Number, default:0},
  aWarned: {type: Number, default:0},
  aWarns: {type: Number, default:0},
  give: {type: Number, default:0}
})
```

and this model

```
const statsModle = mongo.model("statsModle", statsData)
```

I need to get the data by using the `userID` above one each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
YourSchema.fineOne({ _id: userID }, (err, foundUser) => {
    // foundUser is the data you want
})
```

If you want to fetch the document via an `id` you can even use a simpler version:

```
YourSchema.findById(userID, (err, foundUser) => {
    // ...
})
```

Comment: i tested this and i got the data i wanted but how do i split it؟

Comment: Can you  elaborate what you mean by "splitting" it?